# Accessing metadata of an extent (data shard)

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am trying to understand anatomy of an extent. Is there any admin command or tool to display metadata of an extent ? There is a `.show table <tablename> extents` command but it doesn't display all the metadata information that the documentation says extents store.

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding the missing metadata i.e. what exactly is missing?

Comment: e.g. max and min values stored for each of the datetime columns in the table. I read that extent stores min and max values for each datetime column in the table. I guess this information is not exposed by Kusto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information exists but as an internal implementation detail and is not exposed publicly. If you have specific questions please update your question to be more specific and we will be happy to answer.